# How to replace NA's with the mean of variables when the mean is calculated per each Country's data

Tags: python

I need help to code in python to replace NA's with the mean of the variable (suicide rates is the variable, and there are 18 years of data for each country (country is another variable)).  So  I want the mean of the 17 years worth of suicide rates for the specific country to replace the NA for the 18th year.  Example - Saudi Arabia has one year of data missing out of the 18 years.  I want to find the mean of the 17 years suicide rates and replace the NA with that year.  I need to have the code loop through to replace the NA's for every variable.  All variables are rates of suicides or deaths.  The picture shows a highlighted cell which is an example of one that is missing data.  Each country has the data for the 18 years from 1990 to 2018.
[image]

Comment: paste your python code you have so far ... we are waaay too lazy to write from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had this dataframe:

```
   ID  Year       Entity  Variable_1  Variable_2
0   0  2000       Canada       120.0       600.0
1   1  2001       Canada       100.0       700.0
2   2  2002       Canada         NaN       800.0
3   3  2000  Switzerland       300.0       200.0
4   4  2001  Switzerland       400.0         NaN
5   5  2002  Switzerland       500.0       400.0
```

You could create another dataframe with the means for each country and variable:

```
means = df.groupby('Entity').mean()
```

Then you could loop through each country and each variable, and set the missing values to the appropriate mean for that country and variable:

```
for country in df.Entity:

for col in df.drop(columns = ['ID','Year','Entity']).columns:
    
    df.loc[(df.Entity == country) & (df[col].isnull()),col] = means.loc[country,col]
```

Result:

```
   ID  Year       Entity  Variable_1  Variable_2
0   0  2000       Canada       120.0       600.0
1   1  2001       Canada       100.0       700.0
2   2  2002       Canada       110.0       800.0
3   3  2000  Switzerland       300.0       200.0
4   4  2001  Switzerland       400.0       300.0
5   5  2002  Switzerland       500.0       400.0
```